# Dead lock on Singleton call

Tags: objective-c, singleton

When I initialize a singleton like this, I found it will lead to dead lock.

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, assign) BOOL flag;
@end

@implementation A

+(instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static id instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        instance = self.new;
    });
    return instance;
}

-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {
        [A sharedInstance].flag = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Is there any way to break it?

Comment: Just a guess, but don't call `sharedInstance` from the `init` routine that `sharedInstance` calls.

Comment: Note that "dot syntax" use should be restricted to properties and/or setting/getting, not calling methods with side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
[A sharedInstance].flag = YES;
```

Change it to this:

```
self.flag = YES; // or _flag = YES;
```

As you have it, the `init` tries to access the singleton while the singleton is still being created.